# Immutable.js split key of type Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Consider the following [example](https://codepen.io/johnfoo/pen/wXydej?editors=0012) using Immutable's `List` and `Map` collections:

```
const Map = Immutable.Map;
const List = Immutable.List;

const origin = List([Map({name: 'element1', groupKey: Map({id1: 'foo', id2: 'bar'})}), Map({name: 'element2', groupKey: Map({id3: 'foo'})})]);

console.log("Origin:", String(origin));

const grouped = origin.groupBy( el => el.get('groupKey'));

console.log("Grouped:", String(grouped));

console.log("Expected", "OrderedMap { 'id1': List [ Map { 'name': 'element1', 'groupKey': Map { 'id1': 'foo', 'id2': 'bar' } } ], 'id2': List [ Map { 'name': 'element1', 'groupKey': Map { 'id1': 'foo', 'id2': 'bar' } } ], 'id3': List [ Map { 'name': 'element2', 'groupKey': Map { 'id3': 'foo' } } ] }");
```

Basically, what I'm searching for is a way to group the contained maps from `origin` by `groupKey`in a way where each of the ids (`id1`, `id2`, `id3`) points to the beloging maps:

```
{
 id1: [{'name': 'element1', ...}],
 id2: [{'name': 'element1', ...}],
 id3: [{'name': 'element2', ...}],
}
```

I could not figure out how to split the resulting keys as returned from  `groupBy` (which are Maps in this case). I tried to use the [mapping functions](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/map) provided by the API but it seems they cannot be used to alter the cardinality as needed.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `el.get('groupKey')` is a unique map. Therefore, every element is in it's own group.

The `groupBy` function cannot group by multiple keys, every element will go in a single group.

```
const origin = List([
  Map({name: 'element1', groupKey: 'banana'}), 
  Map({name: 'element2', groupKey: 'rocket'}),
  Map({name: 'element3', groupKey: 'rocket'}),
  Map({name: 'element4', groupKey: 'rocket'}),
]);

const groupedMap = origin.groupBy( el => el.get('groupKey'));
// results in:
// "OrderedMap { 'banana': List [ Map { 'name': 'element1', 'groupKey': 'banana' } ], 'rocket': List [ Map { 'name': 'element2', 'groupKey': 'rocket' }, Map { 'name': 'element3', 'groupKey': 'rocket' }, Map { 'name': 'element4', 'groupKey': 'rocket' } ] }"
```

If you want to group by multiple values, as in your example, then you need to write your own grouping function. A list would probably make more sense for the grouping keys, but let's stick to the example:

```js
const Map = Immutable.Map;
const List = Immutable.List;
const OrderedMap = Immutable.OrderedMap;

const origin = List([
  Map({name: 'element1', groupKey: Map({id1: 'foo', id2: 'bar'})}),
  Map({name: 'element2', groupKey: Map({id3: 'foo'})}),
  Map({name: 'element3', groupKey: Map({id99: 'bar'})}),
  Map({name: 'element4'}),
]);

function groupByMap(map, mapKey) {
  const groups = {};
  let keyMap;
  map.forEach(elem => {
    keyMap = elem.get(mapKey);
    if (Immutable.isCollection(keyMap)) {
      keyMap.valueSeq().forEach(k => {
        if (!groups[k]) {
          groups[k] = [elem];
        } else {
          groups[k].push(elem);
        }
      });
    } else if(groups['lost+found']){
      groups['lost+found'].push(elem);
    } else {
      groups['lost+found'] = elem;
    }
  });
  return Immutable.fromJS(groups);
}

const grouped = groupByMap(origin, 'groupKey');
console.log("Grouped:", String(grouped));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```